# gitlab runner confusion - should the service be running?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So I have configured my gitlab-ci.yaml file -

```
build:
    script:
        "python /root/test.py"
    only:
       - master
       - atest
       - triggers
```

the script simply returns 0 or 1 
This all works, but my confusion comes from whether or not the gitlab-runner should be running because whether it is or not seems to make no difference. Whereas everything I have read says the service should be running.

Please can someone clear this up for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to run on `your` dedicated runner, you could add a tag to your runner when registering it, or alternatively on the CI/CD settings page(edit runner and add tag)

Then add this tag to your  `gitlab-ci.yaml`

```
build:
    script:
        "python /root/test.py"
    only:
       - master
       - atest
       - triggers
    tags:
       - <myrunnertag>
```

In this way, this script will be executed by your runner.